# unlock files in team foundation server 2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

After moving TFS from one server to another, facing problems with locks.

At the time of moving TFS to another server some files checked out. After moving TFS to another server these files checked out by previous server usernames. How to remove all previous usernames and their locks on files.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2):

**Multiple Options**

- [Update the identities in TFS so the old users map to the new ones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253054.aspx)
- change the owner of the old workspaces to the new user (See ["How to change the owner of a TFS Workspace"](http://www.bandgap.cs.rice.edu/classes/comp410/resources/Using%20TFS/How%20to%20change%20the%20owner%20of%20a%20TFS%20workspace.aspx))
- delete the old workspaces using "tf workspace /delete"
- Use the command  "tf lock" as an administrator (See [Undo / Unlock for Others with Team Foundation Version Control](http://weblogs.asp.net/dmckinstry/archive/2006/07/09/Undo-_2F00_-Unlock-for-Others-with-Team-Foundation-Version-Control.aspx))

Comment: Hi Betty,

Can you please provide sample tf commands to unlock files

Comment: added, sorry stack overflow doesn't seem to like the link much.

Comment: @john-saunders that url referencing thing is awesome!